# Installing ScrapyJS - new to python

Tags: python, web-scraping, installation, scrapy, scrapyjs

I'm trying to use this scrapy addon (or what it is): [scrapyjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs).

However there are no install instructions and I'm new to Python. Is there something basic here that I'm missing? How would i integrate this with a scrapy project.

Note: i would prefer to use the Scrapy download handler not the middleware version as it seems like it will be quicker to run. (correct me if im wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Since `scrapyjs` is not a regular python package and is not registered on `PyPI` - first, you need to [clone the repository](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) and move `scrapyjs` package under the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), or into your scrapy project directory (make it "importable").

There are two options to integrate it with `Scrapy`:

- [patching `scrapy` to use `gtk2` reactor](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#download-handler-setup)
- [add a new middleware in settings](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#downloader-middlware-setup):

  ```
  DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
      'scrapyjs.middleware.WebkitDownloader': 1,
  }
  ```

The latter is much easier and cleaner, but would seriously affect performance since each request would be handled in a blocking mode.

Comment: This is basicly the documentation on github. Do i download the zip from github and put it in the same forlder as my scrapy project or? I'm completely new to Python. Can you please write a bit more basic introduction?

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm sure, updated the answer. Check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, however I'm stil not completely sure how to do this. How do i move the scrapyjs package under the sys.path? Can you give me an example? Sorry for being a complete noob at this :-/.

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm try putting it near your `scrapy.cfg` file - this should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, i think i got it working now. However i need to install dependencies. Can you maybe take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919985/how-to-install-python-gtk2-python-webkit-and-python-jswebkit-on-osx) and see if you are able to give a more complete answer? How do i install jswebkit for example?

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm oh yeah, I remember that "exciting adventure", please don't ask me to dive into it again :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to alecxe's answer, for Ubuntu/Debian systems, first install the dependencies (webkit, gtk2 and jswebkit)

```
sudo apt-get install python-jswebkit libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 python-webkit
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2 python-gnome2 python-glade2 python-gobject
```

If you are working with a virtualenv you'll have to symlink the libs you installed

```
mkdir your-venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0* lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygtk.pth lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/ lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glib/ lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairo lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webkit lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jswebkit.so lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

To use the patch method, find out where your scrapy lives (if you don't already)

```
python -c "import scrapy; print scrapy.__file__"
```

This will give you the location of the compiled bytecode of Scrapy's `__init__.py`. Go to that directory and add the following lines in `__init__.py`

```
from twisted.internet import gtk2reactor
gtk2reactor.install()
```

Comment: Thank you again :). The problem is that I'm trying to get this to work on OSX and Windows aswell (first OSX). It seems like no one knows how to install python-webkit and python-jswebkit on OSX... Are you able to find this out?